# How do I call a static method on a generic class without specifying a type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class that is generic, as follows:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
     public void SetValue(T value){...}
     public T GetValue(){...}
     public static void ClearAll(){...}
}
```

I want to invoke the static method from time to time.  Ideally, something like:

```
MyClass.Clear();
```

The compiler complains that

> Using the generic type 'MyClass' requires 1 type arguments.

I'm able to call it as follows:

```
MyClass<object>.Clear();
```

I feel like the extra `<object>` clutters up the code unnecessarily.  However, I can't simply remove the `<T>` from the class declaration, as it would not be possible to infer `T` from usage in the `GetValue()` method.  Is there some way to define the class such that the public static method does not require type parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a separate class with the same name but no type parameters.

Note that the type parameters are part of the identity of the class.  If you're trying to clear all fields in all type-parameterized versions of your class, that isn't directly possible.